# Final table shuffle in MTT

Tags: mtt

Last night I was playing in a MTT at the local casino and when the tournament was down to the final table, the players were shuffled. The floor managers gave us cards to pick with the position number.

Is this a regular practice in non-online MTTs?

I found it to be annoying for two reasons:

1. I was the chip lead, and had to haul my chips across the table.
2. Before the shuffle I was on the button and after shuffle landed in the big blind, therefore I paid BB and SB twice in fewer than 10 turns.

Comment: Yes, it's common. I played a tourney at the Orleans once where I had just made it past the blind when we got down to 10 players, paying 9. They redrew for the final, I got the big blind (for my whole stack) and immediately busted on the bubble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard procedure. Everyone redraws for the final table for the sake of fairness. There is a player from the other table also on the button, players also in the blinds etc. Why would it be right for players at your table to keep their seats when the other players loose their seats when the final table starts. This also  solves the problem of players having to sit out one hand or more when the seat they come to is between the button and the small blind.

Comment: Thank you. Hehe, I haven't thought about it from the point of view of those that have to move to my table :)